# How to draw the tableau of an inference

Tags: logic

I apologise if this may sound like a stupid question (I have searched online but couldn't find an answer) Is there a way to draw the tableau of an inference? 
For example if I have the following inference, how can I show using the tableau that the inference is true or not?

∀x,∀y(P(x, y)→P(y, x)), P(a, b) ⊢P(b, b)

Answer (score 2):

There are some *beautiful* books :

- Raymond Smullyan, [First-Order Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=kgvhQ-oSZiUC&pg=PA54) (1968)

and

- Peter Smith, [An Introduction to Formal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=bX91C6GOBkcC&pg=PA228) (2003),

but also :

- Mordechai Ben-Ari, [Mathematical Logic for Computer Science](https://books.google.it/books?id=TQ1n03kEBOkC&pg=PA33) (3rd ed - 2012).

---

In order to show if : $∀x∀y(P(x,y) → P(y,x)), P(a,b) ⊢ P(b,b)$ holds or not, we have to proceeed as for the propositional case, considering (for *signed* tableau) the set :

> $S = \{ T \ ∀x∀y(P(x,y) → P(y,x)), T \ P(a,b), F \ P(b,b) \}$;

if it closes, then the set is *unsatisfiable* and thus the formula $P(b,b)$ is *logical consequence* of the premises.

The only rule we can apply to start with is $T \ \forall$ (twice) [see : R.Smullyan, page 54].